# Non-maximum suppression in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I applied a harris corner detection using openCV which gave me a response map for the potential corners. The documentation states that corners can be found as the local maxima of this response map - does anyone know how this can be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a working implementation with full coding for both Harris and the Shi-Tomasi  corner detectors [here](http://fahmifahim.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/opencv-corner-detection/). The 4th parameter in the corner detector function is a CvPoint2D32f* structure. The function returns the calculated local maxima i.e. the corners into this structure array. Simply looping through the array and receiving each point as a CvPoint will get you the corner positions.

(all this is there in the code)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ended up writing my own implementation - pretty simple, just use an nxn sliding window and keep track of the local maximum.